# Win64 GhostPCL unable to display Unix PCL

Tags: java, printer-control-language

I have created a Java app that generates a PCL file via FOP.  When I run the Java app on my local Windows box I can view the generated PCL file using GhostPCL.  I can also run the same Java app on a Unix server and generate the PCL file.  However, when I copy the PCL file from the Unix server to my windows laptop GhostPCL will not display the PCL file.  I don't get a error, just the GhostPCL usage text.

I've tried various methods to convert the PCL file from Unix to Windows, but nothing has worked.

I'm just trying to verify the contents of the generated PCL from the Unix server (which includes text files and PDFs).  I've viewed the source of both Windows and Unix generated PCL files and they 'look' similar'

Is this a Unix to Windows issue or could there be an issue in my FOP implementation on a Unix OS.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm using winscp to copy the file from Unix to my windows box.  Never had an issue before with viewing regular text files on my Windows box that I copied from Unix, so I was wondering if it was an implementation issue instead of a format issue.

Comment: I verified the md5 sums were the same.

Answer (score 0):

I'm embarrassed to say, but the issue was simply a typo in the command to view the file in GhostPCL.  Able to view the PCL file generated by java app running on Unix.